# How to get number of bytes consumed by unpack

Tags: perl, unpack

Is there a way to get number of bytes that "consumed" by an 'unpack' call?
  I just want to parse(unpack) different structures from a long string in several steps, like following:

```
my $record1 = unpack "TEMPLATE", substr($long_str, $pos);

# Advance position pointer
$pos += NUMBER_OF_BYTES_CONSUMED_BY_LAST_UNPACK();

# Other codes that might determin what to read in following steps
# ...

# Read again at the new position
my $record2 = unpack "TEMPLATE2", substr($long_str, $pos);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does seem like a glaring omission in `unpack`, doesn't it? As a consolation prize, you could use an `a*` to the end of the unpack template to return the unused portion of the input string.

```
# The variable-length "w" format is to make the example slightly more interesting.
$x = pack "w*", 126..129;
while(length $x) {
    # unpack one number, keep the rest packed in $x
    ($n, $x) = unpack "wa*", $x;
    print $n;
}
```

If your packed string is really long, this is not a good idea since it has to make a copy of the "remainder" portion of the string every time you do an unpack.

Comment: Thanks Wumpus, that solution solved my problem although there are memory and CPU usage penalty for copying strings :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the character `.` to the end of the format string:

```
my (@ary) = unpack("a4v3a*.", "abcdefghijklmn");

say for @ary;
```

Output:

```
abcd
26213
26727
27241
klmn
14 # <-- 14 bytes consumed
```

This was cleverly hidden in the [perl5100delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta#Byte/character-count-feature-in-unpack%28%29) file. If it is documented in perlfunc somewhere, I cannot find it.